# Trying to get the right json data to Page. JavaScript Node.Js

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
app.get('/book/:bibleBook/:bibleChapter/:bibleVerse', (req, res) => {
    const book = req.params.bibleBook;
    const chapter = req.params.bibleChapter;
    const verse = req.params.bibleVerse;
    const bibleVerse = [
        {
          "id": 1001001,
          "Book": "Genesis",
          "Chapter": 1,
          "Verse": 1,
          "Text": "In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth."
        },
        {
          "id": 1001002,
          "Book": "Genesis",
          "Chapter": 1,
          "Verse": 2,
          "Text": "And the earth was without form, and void; and darkness was upon the face of the deep. And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters."
        },
        {
          "id": 1001003,
          "Book": "Genesis",
          "Chapter": 1,
          "Verse": 3,
          "Text": "And God said, Let there be light: and there was light."
        },
        {
          "id": 1001004,
          "Book": "Genesis",
          "Chapter": 1,
          "Verse": 4,
          "Text": "And God saw the light, that it was good: and God divided the light from the darkness."
        },
        {
          "id": 1001005,
          "Book": "Genesis",
          "Chapter": 1,
          "Verse": 5,
          "Text": "And God called the light Day, and the darkness he called Night. And the evening and the morning were the first day."
        }
    ]
    res.send('This is ' + book + ' ' + chapter + ':' + verse);
});
```

Good evening. I am working on a website. And I'm a trying to post json data from file below on a page. It worked for me to make a url for the verse. And on the page I get the book, chapter and verse. does anybody can explain to me how I can get the text from the bibelVerse on the right page.

Comment: Can you tell me one example input and output, I don't sure that I am understanding you now.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to return the verse text, you need to write something that will find the correct verse in your array. So I'd do something like this...

```
let foundVerse = bibleVerse.find(function(verseEl) {
    return verseEl.book === book && verseEl.chapter === chapter && verseEl.verse === verse;
});
```

You'll probably also want to validate these values you're getting from `req.params` to make sure you have data that is valid.

At this point, you'll either have the item that matches or a `null` object for `foundVerse`. So you can write some logic to send back the correct response (I assume the text?).

```
if (foundVerse) {
    return res.send(foundVerse.Text);
}
return res.status(404).send("No verse found.");
```